# Bootstrap - Can not remove the right margin

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

I have an issue on http://kovaneruze.cz. There is a right margin/padding on the page, here is the image:

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpZV1.png)

I have a padding: 0px property on container-fluid div, so the image and items sticks right to the sides of the page. If I remove it, tha margin disappears, but the content is not right to the side. Here are the images:

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdD2W.png)

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/170HD.png)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: show your code please

Comment: and what version of bootstrap??

Comment: The version of bootstrap is Bootstrap 4. Here is the code:  http://jsfiddle.net/4j01hwsz/

Comment: i dont see any space i see scroll bar

Comment: I have fixed the space already by the right answer below, thank you. Now I am trying to figure out, how to style the rest of the cols/rows so it sticks to the side but don't make any extra space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add padding left and right 0px to col-md-12

```
<div class="row" style="padding: 0px;">
        <div class="col-md-12 margin-0 wow fadeIn" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeIn;padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;">
            <img src="http://kovaneruze.cz/images/ruze1.jpg" width="100%">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This just fixed the right margin top column, but other columns still don't stick to the side.